# Give $[0,1]^{\omega}$ the uniform topology. Find an infinite subset of this space that has no limit point.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

**Give $[0,1]^{\omega}$ the uniform topology. Find an infinite subset of this space that has no limit point.**

I know there are many post about this question but I would like to understand this solution that I found on the internet, could someone help me please?

**Interesting. $A=\{x_i=(0,...,0,1,0,...)\}$ has no limit point (if $x$ has a coordinate in $(0,1)$ then a small enough ball does not contain any other point in $A$ , otherwise the distance to any point in $A$ is either $0$ or $1$).**

I do not understand this:
 (if $x$ has a coordinate in $(0,1)$ then a small enough ball does not contain any other point in $A$ , otherwise the distance to any point in $A$ is either $0$ or $1$)

Comment: What is your definition of "uniform topology"?

Comment: @ZacharySelk
It is the topology generated by the uniform metric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $(e_i)$ is an infinite subset of $[0,1]^\omega$ which has no limit point because $d(e_i,e_j)=\sup|e_i-e_j|=1$ where $e_i$ has $1$ in the $i^{th}$ co-ordinate and $0's$ elsewhere.

The uniform metric is given by $d(\overline x,\overline y)=\sup_{i\in I} |x_i-y_i|$ where $\overline x=(x_i),\overline y=(y_i)$

Since $e_i,e_j$ differ in atleast one co-ordinate so $d(e_i,e_j)=1$

If the sequence $(e_i)_i$ has to have a limit point then after a finite number of terms distance between any two terms must be very very small(which is what the definition of limit point says) which is not here as $d(e_i,e_j)=1$
 for $i\neq j$

Comment: It seems this is showing that the sequence $e_i$ is not convergent. I believe what we want is that the sequence has no convergent subsequence, so I don't think we can use that for large enough $i$ $d(e_i, e_j)$ is small.